# Unable to run curlpp on Xcode

Tags: c++

In C++ within Xcode I am using curlpp, yet I get prompted with the following error: Undefined symbol: curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup(). I've read that I must add the following flags to the compiler: -lcurlpp, -lcurl. Yet, once I have added them, I still get the same issue.

[image]

Comment: @limserhane No. I am including cURLpp.hpp and Options.hpp